# Cómo modificar un elemento creado desde C# en Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, microsoft

Tengo este fragmento de código por ejemplo para crear un `Label`:

```
            var label1 = new Label
            {
                Text = "Elemento 1",
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };
            AgregarElementos.Children.Add(label1);
```

El detalle está en que por ejemplo un botón hace que ese `label` se crea con esas propiedades, está dentro de un `if` así:

```
        if (item1 == 0)
        {
            var label1 = new Label
            {
                Text = "Elemento 1",
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };
            AgregarElementos.Children.Add(label1);
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = item1.ToString();
        }
        item1++;
```

Solamente se crea una vez, puesto que una vez se crea, `item1` se incrementa a 1 y ya no vuelve a generarse ese botón. Mi problema viene que al estar creado dentro de un `if`, no tengo posibilidad de acceder desde fuera de ese `if`, por ejemplo en el `else` me da error diciendo que `label1` no existe en el contexto actual. ¿De qué forma podría hacerlo público o global el `label1`?

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente declara la label fuera del if (no es necesario que la inicialices si no quieres, pero te puede dar NullReferenceException en el else si no te cubres):

```
        var label1 = new Label();
        if (item1 == 0)
        {
            label1 = new Label
            {
                Text = "Elemento 1",
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };
            AgregarElementos.Children.Add(label1);
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = item1.ToString();
        }
        item1++;
```